# Wrapping rxjs observable to do something before and after (for example show/hide loading screen)

Tags: typescript, rxjs, rxjs6

I am trying to create function which wraps given Observable and adds loading screen to it.
The function `function wrapWithLoadingScreen<T>(obs$: Observable<T>): Observable<T>` should work like :

1. show loading screen.
2. execute observable received as parameter
3. hide loading screen after all values are emitted.

My initial idea of implementation was:

```
function wrapWithLoadingScreen<T>(obs$: Observable<T>): Observable<T> {
  return of(null).pipe(
    tap(() => console.log("show loading screen")),
    switchMap(() => obs$),
    finalize(() => console.log("hide loading screen"))
  );
}
```

but when i chain other operators to result of this function then "hide loading screen" is executed after those chains (not after original observable finishing).

Here is an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-wrapping-observable

the result in console of above is

```
show loading screen
im reducing
im reducing
reducing finished so loading screen should be hidden
the result is 6
hide loading screen
```

what im aiming for should be

```
show loading screen
im reducing
im reducing
hide loading screen
reducing finished so loading screen should be hidden
the result is 6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `finalize` is executed after the teardown, see this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/reactivex/rxjs/issues/5357) for more info. That means that even though you are using `finalize` in the middle of the chain, even before the `reduce` and `mergeMap`, it will be executed last during the teardown process.

As for the alternative solution for your problem, you can use `tap` like so:

```
function wrapWithLoadingScreen<T>(obs$: Observable<T>): Observable<T> {
  return of(null).pipe(
    tap(() => console.log("show loading screen")),
    switchMap(() => obs$),
    tap(
      () => {},
      () => console.log("hide loading screen"),
      () => console.log("hide loading screen")
    ),
  );
}
```

Besides the `next` callback, you can provide the `error` and `complete` callbacks to the `tap` operator. See [RxJS Tap Doc](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/tap) for more info about the error and complete callbacks.

Comment: Didn't know you can tap onError and onComplete. Thank you, works perfect.